# Neo4J ETL from SQL Server: Import from views

Tags: neo4j

I'm currently trying to use the Neo4J ETL import (https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-etl/) to import some data from an existing SQL Server data warehouse to a new Neo4J Graph database.
Everything working fine, but interesting enough, the Neo4J model transformation logic doesn't seem to take views into consideration. The description on the link above also mentions just three mapping logics:

- A table with a foreign key is treated as a join and imported as a
  node with a relationship
- A table with 2 foreign keys is treated as a join table and imported
  as a relationship
- A table with >2 foreign keys is treated as n intermediate node and
  imported as a node with multiple relationships

Interesting enough, I really don't find any further information and similar topics are several years old. It seems odd, that this feature is not possible, as I would guess transferring an existing data warehouse to a Graph database wouldn't be something out of the ordinary?

Unfortunately, I can't give much more information, as there just doesn't seem to be more. Am I using the tool conceptually wrong or is this feature never worth being mentioned?

Comment: best to create an issue -> https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-etl
In the meantime, you can apply custom logic for exporting data from SQL server, some examples in the docs: https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/database-integration/load-jdbc/#_load_jdbc_examples
And I also wrote a blog some time ago: https://tbgraph.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/neo4j-apoc-load-jdbc/

Comment: @TomažBratanič Thank you, I'm going to check your blog